# StyleCop SuppressionMessage

Tags: stylecop

How to use suppression for custom rules?

Comment: isn't that kinda the opposite of why you would create a custom StyleCop rule??

Comment: @Mitch: There are sometimes edge cases that are difficult to treat appropriately in a rule.  If they're infrequent enough, it may not be worthwhile spending time making the rule "smarter".  This is particularly true in a custom rule intended for internal consumption rather than wide public deployment.

Answer (score 4):

You can suppress custom rule violations using SuppressMessageAttribute in exactly the same manner as is done for rules that ship as part of StyleCop. e.g.:

```
[SuppressMessage("Your.Analyzer.Namespace", "AA1000:RuleName")]
```

(where the namespace, rule ID, and rule name must all be replaced by the actual values for the rule)

Comment: Note that in my case, I had to put the **fully qualified name of the analyzer class** (the one that derives from `StyleCop.SourceAnalyzer`), not just the namespace, and that fully qualified name was different from what VisualStudio showed in the warnings list (it showed `MyCustomRules.Custom`, but the fully qualified name of the analyzer class was `MyCustomRules.CustomRules`).

Answer (score 2):

I use the fact that stylecop ignores regions with "generated code" in title and do the following:

```
#region Stylecop will ignore regions with "generated code" in title, like this.

//...code you don't want style cope to test code goes here

#endregion
```